# angular2/webpack template 404 errors

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I followed this tutorial and got everything just like the tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4i1nLrqMR14#t=563.837081

Now it's time to grow my application so I created an html file for my component, and set my templatURL to `templateUrl: './app.html'` since it's in the same directory which is root/app/app.html.  I received an error because it's looking for it at root/app.html.  See attachment for project structure and error.

Command for dev change tracking:

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 4000 --content-base src
```

[image]

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
     "types": [
       "core-js",
       "node"
     ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    //entry:'./src/main.ts',
    entry:{
        'polyfills':'./src/polyfills.browser.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.browser.ts',
        'main': './src/main.ts',
    },
    output:{
        path:'./dist',
        //filename:'app.bundle.js'
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'


    },
    module:{
        loaders:[{test:/\.ts$/, loader:'ts-loader'}]
    },
    resolve:{
         root: [ path.join(__dirname, 'src') ], //add this for dev server
        extensions:['','.js','.ts']
    },
    plugins:[

        //inject all the files above into this file
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ]


}
```

Comment: Webpack sometimes has problems via change tracking/hot reloading. My guess it that your problem will be alleviated just by restarting the dev server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lost track of where I found this answer but with webpack, If I want it to work, in my component, I have to add

```
moduleId: module.id,
```